# Can a leased line be wireless?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, cable

Is it necessary for a leased line to be a physical line or it can be wireless?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be wireless. There are providers already providing Wireless Leased Lines straight to the office.
Here is the Link : [Froya](http://www.froya.co.uk/wireless-leased-line-internet-access)